# Declaration is not allowed on the initialization block part

Tags: c, variables, initialization, declaration

```
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "helper2.h"

char validLoop = ' ';
int choice;
int validInput = 0;

main(){

 repeat:
 clrscr();

 printf("=======================\nMenu\n=======================\n[1] Binary to Decimal\n[2] Sorting Algorithm(Ascending Descending)\n[3] Palindrome Checker\n=======================\n");

 do{
 printf("Enter Your Choice: ");
 scanf("%d", &choice);

 if (choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3){
     validInput = 1;
 }

 else{
     printf("Invalid Input! Please Input a value given within the choices.\n");
 }

 } while(validInput == 0);


 if (choice == 1){
     BinToDec();
 }

 if (choice == 2){
     sorting();
 }

 if (choice == 3){
     checker();
 }

 printf("\nPress Y||y to repeat or any key to exit.");
 validLoop = getche();

 if (validLoop == 'y' || validLoop == 'Y'){
 goto repeat;
 }

 else{
 return 0;
 }

}
```

im getting errors on where my validLoop, choice, and validInput isnt being initialized and says "Declaration is not allowed here." it also says a statement is missing a ; on line 11. am i doing something wrong in my part?

edit: sorry, i forgot to add the header:

```
char checker(){
    int i;
    int check = 0;
    char checker();
    char word[50];
    printf("Insert a string: ");
    scanf("%s", &word);
    for (i=0;i<strlen(word)/2;i++){

        if (word[i] == word[strlen(word)-i-1]){
            check++;
        }
    }


    if (check == strlen(word)/2){
        printf("%s is a palindrome", word);
    }

    else{
        printf("%s is not a palindrome", word);
    }

    return 0;

}

int BinToDec(){
    char binary[8];
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    int value;
    int length;


    printf("Input binary number you want to convert to decimal: "); 
    scanf("%s", binary);

    length = strlen(binary);


    for (i=strlen(binary)-1;i>=0;i--){
        value = length - (i + 1);
        if ((int)binary[i]-48 == 1){
            sum = sum + pow(2.0, (float)value);
        }
    }

  printf("%d", sum);
  getch();

  return 0;

}




int sorting(){
    int i;
    int sort[10];
    int min;
    int temp;
    int currentElement;
    int compareElement;

    printf("Input integers to sort: ");
     for (i=0;i<10;i++){
             scanf("%d", &sort[i]);

     for (currentElement=0;currentElement<(sizeof(sort)/sizeof(sort[0]))-1;currentElement++){
        min = currentElement;

        for (compareElement=currentElement+1;compareElement<(sizeof(sort)/sizeof(sort[0]))-1;compareElement++){
            if (sort[compareElement] < sort[currentElement]){
                min = compareElement;
            }
        }

        temp = sort[currentElement];
        sort[currentElement] = sort[min];
        sort[min] = temp;
    }

    printf("Ascending Order: ");

    for (currentElement=0;currentElement<=(sizeof(sort)/sizeof(sort[0]))-1;currentElement++){
        printf("%d, ", sort[currentElement]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("Descending Order: ");

    for (currentElement=(sizeof(sort)/sizeof(sort[0]))-1;currentElement>=0;currentElement--){
        printf("%d, ", sort[currentElement]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

basically the whole this is supposed to be a program to call my functions from the header file. everything was smooth sailing and it was even working before i tried adding validations on my part. i dont know if this really helps but i would appreciate every feedback with this. im using a turbo c emulator as my compiler and working environment.

Comment: Include your `helper2.h` header in your code post.

Comment: Seems like there's something dodgy in your `helper2.h` file -  but, as you don't show us what this is, we can't really say *what's* wrong.

Comment: You are also missing `int` before `main`, unless you are using a really old version of C where this was not required. (And even then you should put it there.)

Comment: Overall, pay attention to the structure and indentation of your code (as well as preserving that formatting here, e.g., use the `{}` button in the editor). The `goto` can be replaced by a loop (e.g., `do { … } while (validLoop == 'y')`). And all your variables could be local to (inside) `main` instead of global.

Comment: I guess a missing `}` or something else which can throw everything out of alignment.

Comment: Eeek! You have code in your header file? Seriously, header files should only contain declarations and definitions, the code should be in a .c file.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Input integers to sort: ");
 for (i=0;i<10;i++){
         scanf("%d", &sort[i]);
```

Seems closing `}` is missing.  Writing actual definitions in header is not a good habit.

Comment: Yep now that I've copied it all out and checked, well spotted.

Comment: This actually solved the problem, thanks! For everyone who actually helped me debugging my stupid program, I'll keep in mind that I don't repeat such kind of work and improve my style of programming. Again, thank you!

Comment: @eiennv225 you can still get perplexing errors from missing a `}` This particular code made no real difference being in the header: the compiler just includes it, it could have been missing from a `typedef`.

Answer (score 0):

Other coding issues aside.
In the code that you show is in your header file you have the following line:

```
    char checker();
```

within function     `char checker()` I suspect that this is your culprit.